# Confusion about a basis for a topology

Tags: general-topology

Here is Munkres' definition of a basis for a topology:

[image]

I wonder if it is assumed that when one talks about a basis for a topology, then the topology being considered is the topology generated by this basis? The reason I'm confused are these two theorems:

[image]

In the highlighted part, he uses that $\tau$ is the topology generated by the basis $\mathcal B$, but he doesn't mention this in hypothesis. So is it implicitly assumed that $\tau$ is the topology generated by $\mathcal B$?

Similarly,

[image]

The second parahraph of the prove says that we must prove that $\tau'=\tau$, but this wasn't claimed in the statement of the theorem.

Comment: He says it in the hypotheses of Lemma 13.1 above the highlighted quote: "let $\mathcal B$ be a basis for the topology $\tau$ on $X$."

Comment: Does it imply that $\tau$ is the topology generated by $\mathcal B$? In the definition, he doesn't say that when one talks about a basis for a topology, then the topology that is meant is the topology generated by the basis.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it implies.

Comment: Yes, that's what he means. To say that "$\tau$ is generated by the basis $\mathcal B$" is equivalent to saying "$\mathcal B$ is a basis for the topology $\tau$." And whenever he brings up a basis, and then refers to a topology, he's talking about the topology generated by the basis (unless otherwise specified).

Comment: There's usually also a separate definition for a basis for a given topology: if you're given topological space $(X, \tau)$, then $\mathcal{B}$ is defined to be a basis for $\tau$ if $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \tau$;  and for every $x \in U \in \tau$, there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x \in B \subseteq U$.  (Then, this condition implies that $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies the condition to be a basis for "some" topology, and the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$ is exactly $\tau$.)

Comment: @user531587 But you're right. This is not really well formulated.

Comment: To expand on amsmath's comment: When you make one definition for "$\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\tau$", and then you make another definition and call it "$\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology", you're sort of presupposing the result that the second definition holds on $\mathcal{B}$ if and only if there exists a topology $\tau$ such that the first definition relates $\mathcal{B}$ and $\tau$ - plus it creates a great potential for confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you that this is confusing here.

You should read the definition at the top as "$\mathcal B$ is a basis for *some* topology on $X$ iff (1) and (2) are satisfied." The topology that it is a basis for is the one generated by $\mathcal B$ according to the next definition. (And I presume that they show this is in fact a topology shortly after.)

Then Lemma 13.1 shows that there is an equivalent definition for the topology generated by $\mathcal B$: the collection of arbitrary unions of sets in $\mathcal B.$ There is a third common equivalent definition: the topology generated by $\mathcal B$ is the intersection of all topologies $\mathcal T$ with $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal T.$

Here is a summary that may be less confusing:

> Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal P(X).$ Then the following are
>   equivalent:
>
> 1. Munkres' (1) and (2) hold.
> 2. The collection of all arbitrary unions of sets in $\mathcal B$ is a topology on $X$.
>
> When these hold, the topology $\mathcal T$ in point 2 is called the topology generated
>   by $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B$ is called a basis for the topology $\mathcal T.$ The topology $\mathcal T$ has the following two alternative
>   characterizations:
>
> 1. $U\in \mathcal T$ iff for all $x\in U$ there is a $B\in \mathcal B$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$
> 2. $\mathcal T$ is the smallest topology such that $\mathcal B\subseteq\mathcal T,$ i.e. the intersection of all such topologies.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things more clear. My new vision of Lemma 13.1 is this. Consider a basis $\mathcal B$ for a topology on a set $X$; then by definition, it is a basis for the topology generated by $\mathcal B$, and the lemma says that this topology, which is denoted by $\mathcal T$, coincides with the topology given by all unions of elements of $\mathcal B$.

Comment: And the proof of Lemma 13.2 also makes more sense now. In the first paragraph, Munkres proves that $\mathcal C$ is a basis for *some* topology. But by definition, it is the basis of the topology generated by $\mathcal C$. The lemma claims that $\mathcal C$ is a basis for the topology on $X$, so one also must prove that the topology generated by $\mathcal C$ is the same as the topology that $X$ comes with initially.

Comment: @user531587 yep, that all sounds reasonable. In other words, in Munkres' formulation, (1) and (2) are necessary and sufficient conditions for $\mathcal B$ to be a basis for some topology, and the topology they are a basis for is the one they generate by the second definition. And a fun fact about this topology is it is exactly the unions of basis sets. Right but so clunky.

Comment: @user531587 I much prefer 'a basis for a topology is a collection of open sets such that any open set can be written as a union of basis sets. And two useful facts about bases are (a) that a collection is a basis for some topology iff (1) and (2) hold. (b) in the event that $\mathcal B$ is a basis for a topology, the topology consists of exactly the sets $U$ such that for all $x\in U$ there is a $B\in \mathcal B$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U.$'

Comment: Why is the topology generated by $\mathcal B$ the *smallest* topology that contains $\mathcal B$? I.e., why is every topology that contains $\mathcal B$ also contains the topology generated by $\mathcal B$?

Comment: @user531587 Since topologies are closed under arbitrary unions, any topology containing all the basis sets contains all the unions of basis sets, and hence all the sets in the topology generated by the basis.